# SSH client delphi open-source library or component, or alternatives

Tags: delphi, ssh

I need my Delphi application to issue very simple commands for example

```
ssh -l userid host.domain.com "df -h"

userid@host.domain.com's password: XXXXX

Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdd5             4.9G  1.7G  3.0G  36% /
/dev/sdc1             1.1G   75M  952M   8% /boot
/dev/sdd2             2.0G   44M  1.8G   3% /var/log
```

Can you recommend any freeware component or library? I've looked in Tory's pages and googled a bit but cannot find any.

I could also look for alternatives if any.

Comment: Just for the record, MobaXterm is Delphi-written SSH and Xserver client. And some sources were open. Did not check their completeness or license https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/license.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can install Cygwin's OpenSSH Client, then call it from your application and capture it's output.

Here is an example on how to capture the console output: 
http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2001/a/bltip0201_2.htm

Keep in mind, that when you are loggin in to an SSH server, the password is requested, in interactive mode (SSH Client will wait until you type the password), so you must configure automatic login, like it's explained here:

http://magicmonster.com/kb/net/ssh/auto_login.html

A little more complicated solution is to use Synapse Lib to connect to the server by using SSL, like this example:

http://www.amsoftwaredesign.com/downloads/synapse_ssh_test.zip

I posted an article in my blog, with a simple class to let you do what you want: http://leonardorame.blogspot.com/2010/01/synapse-based-ssh-client.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for Synapse, exactly what I would recommend, which is a cleaner solution...although it does require 3rd party DLL's (for the SSL implementation), it doesn't require 3rd party software to be installed.

Comment: +1 for your blog post, I've been looking for that for a long time!! Thank you!

Comment: +1 - followed your blog post and it works a treat in D2007, exactly the push in the right direction I needed to get going. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Leonardo, I've used the Synapse solution in FreePascal. One clarification: SSH doesn't use the SSL protocol, but Synapse using Cryptlib can provide the SSH protocol.

Comment: @reiniero,could you please help me to use synaps?

Comment: ssl and ssh are vastly different protocols. Synapse won't help unless it supports ssh too.